# Does every blank canvas produce the same data URL regardless of the size of the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I wanted to know if every blank canvas produces the same data URL so that I can be able to detect if a canvas has something drawn in it or
whether it is empty. Is this also true regardless of size of the canvas?

Comment: You could have easily tested this yourself in a few lines of code...

Answer (score 1):

It does not:

```
<canvas id="one" width="25" height="25"></canvas>
<canvas id="two" width="30" height="30"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
var canvas1  = document.getElementById("one");
var dataUrl1 = canvas1.toDataURL();

var canvas2  = document.getElementById("two");
var dataUrl2 = canvas2.toDataURL();

console.log(dataUrl1);
console.log(dataUrl2);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r1sekxLa/

You can subscribe to canvas draw event to see if it was changed.